# mov edx overwrites cx register

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm

I'm trying to print Hi 10 times. This is my code.

```
section .data

msg db "Hi"

section .text

global _start

_start:

    mov cx, 10


    L1:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, msg
    mov edx, 3
    int 0x80

    dec cx
    jnz L1


    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80
```

gdb reports that mov edx, 3 overwrites the cx register to some crazy value and so the loop keeps going forever.

What am i doing wrong? Is it because they are the same register?

How does one program in assembly with so few registers?

Compiling on centos with nasm and ld

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong line.  The problem is "mov ecx, msg".  ECX is the extended register of which CX is the lower part, so you're writing over it.

It's best to save your loop counter on the stack, because who knows that the 'int' call might change.  Add 'push cx' (or ecx) after 'L1:'. and 'pop cx' after the 'int' call to preserve the contents of the register.

Answer (score 0):

This code fixes it:

```
section .data

msg db "Hi"

counter dw 10

section .text

global _start

_start:




    L1:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, msg
    mov edx, 2
    int 0x80

    mov cx, [counter]
    dec cx
    mov [counter], cx   

    jnz L1


    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80
```

move the value into a variable and then dec it then put it back

Comment: For such a small amount of code, and with no other references to the loop counter, a simple push/pop of cx around the 5 instructions after the L1: label would be highly preferable to reserving a static memory location to store a temporary (i.e. 'local' variable).  Your solution is the equivalent of using a 'static' variable in a high level language.  Local variables in high level languages go on the stack so that the memory use is temporary (using a base pointer instead of push/pop, but it's essentially the same thing).